# How to version control an Android project on Github and use intellij and eclipse IDE by different team members?

Tags: android, eclipse, github, intellij-idea, r.java-file

We have an Android project is sharing on github. Our problem is that I am using eclipse and my team member is using intellij. She doesn't want to switch to eclipse and I don't want to use intellij. I was wondering if there is any chance of conflict between us? 
She has created the project in intellij and share it on github. After I import from github (just following normal procedure as eclipse project) we have this issue in eclipse side. This is what she sees in her IDE. As you can see inside gen folder:

[image]

And this is what I see in my eclipse:
Eclipse suggestion to solve the problem by either importing:

```
import android.R;
```

Or creates class R.java. I appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled android project nature?

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy solution is use of gitignore so you should place all ide and other config files/folder in gitignore  so only ide independent files are pushed and committed to your repository - I imagine that won't cause any issues as you'd be replacing only source files and all your ide config and settings files would remain intact. All you'd have to do is Clean->Rebuild project just to ensure consistency.

From facebook